# Adding two rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy.

The custom post type is news.

The custom taxonomy is new_category.

What I want is the possibility two operate link that:

```
http://example.com/news/ -> show news archive
http://example.com/news/movies/ -> show category movie archive
http://example.com/batman-returns/ -> show post content called "Batman Returns"
```

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^news/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=news&news=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^news/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=news&news_category=$matches[1]','top');
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Change `new_category` taxonomy's rewrite rule while registering**:

```
'rewrite' => ['hierarchical' => false, 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'news']
```

Make sure rewrite rule of `news` post type is default or:

```
'rewrite'  => ['slug' => false, 'with_front' => false]
```

**2. Add rewrite rules for `new_category`**:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?new_category=$matches[1]&post_type=news', 'top');
});
```

**3. Filter `news` post type links**:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function($post_link, $post, $leave_name = false, $sample = false)
{
    if ( 'news' === $post->post_type)
    {
        $post_link = str_replace('/news/', '/', $post_link);
    }

    return $post_link;

}, 10, 4);
```

**4. Add `news` post type to query vars**:

By remove `news` from permalink, WordPress will query posts from `post` post type and you will get 404 not found now. So we need to add our `news` post type to query vars.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query)
{
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( 2 === count($query->query) ) && isset($query->query['name']) )
    {
        $query->set('post_type', ['post', 'news', 'page']);
    }
});
```

That's all. Flush your permalink structure and make sure it is set to `/%postname%/`.

Comment: Thanks @Dan but i was wrong about the final part that I wanted. Sorry.

Your solution was perfect and fit my question, but I need this:

`http://example.com/news/ -> show news archive`
`http://example.com/news/movies/ -> show category movie archive`
`http://example.com/news/batman-returns/ -> show post content called "Batman Returns"`

Comment: @MarcosRezende There're `post` post type and `news` post type. What is archive/post content of what post type? I can't get what you meant.

Comment: I have post post_type and I have news post_type.

The thing is that I dont want http://example.com/batman-returns/ but http://example.com/news/batman-returns/ When I typed my question before I typed wrong. I sad http://example.com/batman-returns/ but I want http://example.com/news/batman-returns/ Do you understand? Sorry about my mistake.

Comment: @MarcosRezende We can't do that because one rewrite rule can't match both category archive (`news/movies/`) and post content (`/news/batman-returns/`). WordPress can't handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Dan. I made `/news/news_category/` and `/news/news_category/batman-returns/`